# BS3 glyphicon padding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have a navbar in a rails app using glyphicons. I can't seem to set the spacing between the glyph and the link label unless I put a " " in front of the label.

[image]

Can  anyone suggest a better solution. Thanks!

```
    <li>
      <%= link_to "Maintenance", dashboards_path, :class=> "glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" %>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have tag and content in a single line it produces no padding. 
Make sure you anchor looks something like:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench">
    Maintenance
  </a>
</li>
```

Or using `link_to`

```
<li>
  <%= link_to dashboards_path, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-wrench' do %>
    <span>Maintenance</span>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Though it seems strange but

`<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench">Maintenance</a>`

produces no spaces between icon and text

[bootply](http://bootply.com/112847)

Comment: Thanks bootply, can you share how to make that work using link_to? Thanks

Comment: just edited that answer with `link_to`. You have to wrap the text with any html tag. I used `span` here.